# The + operator, difference between class types and built-in types?

Tags: c++, function, object, constants, operator-keyword

I'm new to C++. The book I read tells me that if the plus (`+`) operator has been overloaded for some class object, say, the `string` class, to make this problem more concrete.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1("abc");
    string s2("def");

    string s3("def");

    cout<<(s1+s2=s3)<<endl;

    int x=1;
    int y=2
    int z=3;
    cout<<(x+y=z)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you may expect, the first `cout` statement is correct while the second is wrong. The compiler complaints `x+y` is not a modifiable lvalue. My question is why the `+` operator returns a modifiable lvalue for `string` objects but not for `int`?

Comment: In C++, objects are instances of any type, including built-in types. And types are types. So "objects" vs. "built-in types" makes no sense.

Comment: @juanchopanza It would be useful to provide the correct wording while you're at it :)

Comment: @Quentin I guess "difference between built-in types and user-defined types" would be accurate.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It does not return a modifiable lvalue for string. It returns a temporary object, and `s1+s2` and `x+y` are both rvalues.

However, objects of class type may have overloaded `operator=`, which `string` does.  You are allowed to call member functions on rvalues.

The difference between the two cases is in `=` (not `+`)

Comment: Note that this is a problem which is being [worked on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21052529/15416). You can prevent calling `operator=` on rvaliues of your own classes. Problem is, there's existing code that would break if the C++ standard would be changed to forbid assignment to `std::string` rvalues.

Comment: @MSalters Yeah, [a wise man](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598468/does-it-improve-safety-to-mark-assignment-operators-as-lvalue-only) once inquired the same..:)

Answer (score 14):

For `std::string`, `s1 + s2 = s3` is in fact:

```
(operator+(s1, s2)).operator =(s3)
```

`s1 + s2` returns a rvalue

Member methods can be applied to temporary also.
Since C++11, we have the lvalue/rvalue qualifier for method,
so you may forbid `o1 + o2 = o3` for your custom type with:

```
struct Object
{
    Object& operator =(const Object& rhs) & ; // Note the & here
};
```

so `Object::operator =` can only be applied to lvalue.