# Rvalue assignment - primitive vs Class object

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

I've encountered a change in behaviour (at least to my understanding)
between primitives and Classes i've created in c++.
say, the following:

```
int foo()
{
    int a = 4;
    return a;
}

int main() 
{

    foo() = 2;
}
```

of course creates causes a compilation error, because i'm trying to assign
somthing into an rvalue.
But if i were to create my own class, say Complex, the following:

```
Complex foo()
{
    Complex a = Complex(2,4);
    return a;
}

int main() 
{

    foo() = Complex(1,2);
}
```

would actually work. I thought the only way for this to compile is if foo()
returned a reference. 
What am i missing? i assume there is a difference between primitives and 
Classes - isn't the return value of Complex foo() an rvalue?
Thanks!

Comment: @NathanOliver: you have to go home, maybe ?

Comment: I guess what's happening is that your class has an [implicitly-defined move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Trivial_move_constructor), but a fundamental type doesn't.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824750/c-function-returns-a-rvalue-but-that-can-be-assigned-a-new-value and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835686/rvalue-on-the-left-side

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not sure that those are exact duplicates. Those questions deal with the move constructors of user-defined types. This question contrasts the behavior of a primitive type with a user defined type. FWIW, I've been searching a few minutes, and couldn't find anything specific about a primitive type not having a move constructor.

Comment: @AmiTavory Primitives do not need to be moved as moving or copying them is the the same thing.  This question though has nothing to do with moving.  It is about trying to assign a value to an object that is return from a function my value.