# Why std::string a; std::string b; a + b = "abc"; OK？

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, rvalue, copy-assignment

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    a + b = "dadas";
}
```

PS D:\WeCode\local_c++>  & 'c:\Users\z00841303.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.5.1\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-1vidcjmy.adn' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-ur4nmbvf.4bj' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-kdush30f.pk5' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-5hgspuj4.obh' '--dbgExe=D:\Program Files\mingw\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'

a+b is an rvalue expression. Why can a value be assigned in this way?

Comment: Class types don't have the same restriction on rvalues in assignments as primitive types. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835686/why-is-it-possible-to-assign-to-an-rvalue-of-class-type

Comment: @kiner_shah The parentheses are superfluous, operator+ has higher precedence than the assignment operator.

Comment: @Fareanor actually, with class type parentheses may have a meaning. it's an expression. So old-timer style "always write `return (expression);`" is not only wrong, it's also is a source of bugs.

Comment: @Fareanor, I thought without it was failing, didn't check the compilation result properly. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: It is desirable to be able to perform operations on rvalues and `operator=` is just another operation, no reason to restrict it especially because it is overloadable. Surely `(a+b)+c` or `(a+b).size()` are reasonable, both operate on rvalues.

Comment: since c++11 you can have even separate r and lvalue overloads. `std::string::operator=` could make `a + b = "dadas";` an error, but it doesnt. See here for an example: https://godbolt.org/z/1ahj4K756

Comment: the duplicate is about a custom type, but if you look at the `operator=` overloads of `std::string` you can see that the answers apply as well https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D

Comment: I tseems Microsoft implementation looks like legacy code and lacks &&-qualified operator deletion, while compiler already uses new semantic.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I have always disliked that old-timer style, as superfluous and misleading, (makes it look like a function call,) I did not know it also has objective disadvantages.  However, from your comment I was not able to understand what the objective disadvantage exactly is. Can you please explain, in simple basic English terms?

Comment: @MikeNakis one of direct ones - it breaks NRVO. `(x)` is not same identity as `x`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie that was not simple, basic English terms.

Comment: named return-value optimization. It replaces it with unnamed return-value optimization. With that compilers may behave differently. E.g. both GCC and MSVC can disable the former to avoid copy elision (for logging purposes) but they never should skip the latter. But originally style with parents came from Bell C  where it was mandatory: https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf#page=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems one of possible reasons is that *ref-specifiers* for functions were introduced in the C++ Standard after the class template `std::basic_string`  was defined in the C++ Standard. Otherwise the assignment operator could be declared for example like

```
std::basic_string & operator( const std::basic_string & ) &;
```

Here is a demonstration program that shows how to suppress an assignment to rvalue.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct A
    {
        A( int x = 0 ) : x( x ) {}

        A &operator =( const A &a ) &
        {
            x = a.x;

            return *this;
        }

        static A f( const A &a )
        {
            return a;
        }
        int x;
    };

    A a1( 10 );
    std::cout << ( a1 = A::f( A( 20 ) ) ).x << '\n';
    // A::f( A( 20 ) ) = a1; <=== compiler error!
}
```

Anpther reason is to allow chaining operations that defined as functions for user-defined types.

Comment: Hmm, at least that matches GCC implementation, OP issue is Microsoft-specific afaik and they always had salad of features there (like lambdas in VS2010 and Basic-like range for-loop instead of C++ one)