# What do braces on the left-hand side of a variable declaration mean, such as in T {x} = y?

Tags: c++, syntax, initialization, list-initialization, temporary-objects

The code at [this GitHub file](https://github.com/HertzDevil/0CC-FamiTracker/blob/e643e8cbad1c8bf01ff706245d72f93c33417de8/Source/FamiTracker.cpp#L446) uses a C++ variable "declaration" syntax I'm not familiar with:

```
std::unique_ptr<CRecentFileList> {m_pRecentFileList} = std::make_unique<CRecentFileList>(...
```

(`m_pRecentFileList` is declarared in a superclass.)

What does it mean when you wrap a variable **declaration** in braces? (not an initializer list)

---

I extracted a minimal test case which compiles:

```
class foo {
    int* p;
    void f(){
        std::unique_ptr<int> {p} = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    }
};
```

Changing `int* p` to `std::unique_ptr<int> p` creates a compilation error due to `unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;`

This makes me think braced declaration assigns to a outer-scope variable with the same name. I tried creating a test program, but it fails to compile:

```
int main(){
    int x;
    int {x} = 1;
}
```

> `error: using temporary as lvalue [-fpermissive]`

Comment: This is still initializer list, no variable is being declared, instead a temporary is created and move assignment operator is invoked. This code seems to be rather pointless.

Comment: Nice try for MCVE with `int {x} = 1;` BTW. +1.

Comment: I've never gotten this many upvotes and responses quickly before... I'll upvote and/or accept answers tomorrow.

Comment: Coincidentally, you asked on the same day as [a similar question](/q/51172341).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's not a declaration. It's an assignment to a temporary.

In `std::unique_ptr<int> {p} = std::make_unique<int>(1);`, `std::unique_ptr<int> {p}` creates a `unique_ptr` temporary that takes ownership of the object `p` points to, then `std::make_unique<int>(1)` is assigned to that temporary, which causes the object `p` points to to be deleted and the temporary to take ownership of the `int` created by the `make_unique`; finally, at the `;`, the temporary itself is destroyed, deleting the `make_unique`-created `int`.

The net result is `delete p` plus a useless new/delete cycle.

(It would be a declaration had it used parentheses rather than braces:
`std::unique_ptr<int> (p) = std::make_unique<int>(1);` is exactly equivalent to `std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(1);`.)

Comment: What is it used for?

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri: Obfuscating `delete m_pRecentFileList` :-/ (with an useless allocation BTW).

Comment: I think I found the reason this function is broken. The original developer thought he found a clever (as he often does) way of constructing a new object. In reality the object/pointer is deleted as soon as it's constructed, causing the app to crash after the function's called (since the pointer's reset to 0xCCCCCCCC).

Comment: @jimbo1qaz The original pointer (`m_pRecentFileList`) isn't even updated to point to the temporary object, but one way or another it is indeed "clever" code with undefined behavior.

Comment: So looking at [earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598468/does-it-improve-safety-to-mark-assignment-operators-as-lvalue-only), this "probably" shouldn't be allowed, but it is because nobody's bothered to sit down and prove that restricting the default to prevent this is a completely safe idea?

Comment: Correction: Visual Studio debug build resets the deleted pointer to 0xDDDDDDDD. And somehow the original pointer is mutated, not the temporary unique_ptr constructed *from* it.

Comment: @Leushenko There is an idiom to call swap on a temporary, e.g. `std::vector<X>().swap(myVec);` – which predates C++11 and now should be replaced by e.g. move-assignment most of the time – but generally I think you are right: Assigning to a temporary usually indicates a bug. Scott Meyers in his book "Effective C++" (IIRC) recommended returning object types as `const` to avoid mutating operations on temporaries. In C++11 or higher, this could be better solved by adding lvalue ref-qualifiers on mutating methods. However, it seems the issue was not considered important enough for the std. lib. yet