# What is going on here? I assign result to result in C++

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

Could you tell me what is going on here? And why it is possible?

```
std::make_unique<int>(1) = std::make_unique<int>(1);
```

I thought that `make_unique` returned an r-value...

**Edit:**
Could you provide some useful example of this construction?

Comment: Related to [what-do-braces-on-the-left-hand-side-of-a-variable-declaration-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170417/in-c-what-do-braces-on-the-left-hand-side-of-a-variable-declaration-mean)

Comment: @Jarod42 I know that, because I checked that question and I got this fragment of code meanwhile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I thought that return of make_unique is r-value...

It is. But for class types like `std::unique_ptr<...>`, the assignment is a call to an overloaded member function. You can pass rvalues as arguments to functions. And more specifically, call member functions on rvalues.

---

As an example, when you examine `std::bitset`, you see that its `reference` type is in fact a class type. The assignment operator for that type is overloaded. It accepts a `bool`, but in fact performs a bit-wise operation to manipulate a flag in the packed memory of the `bitset`.

---

It works for `unique_ptr` rvalues because it's overloaded (and is implicitly generated for other class types) without any ref-qualifiers. I.e.

```
unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr&& r ) noexcept;
```

... and not...

```
unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr&& r ) & noexcept;
// Can only be used on lvalues, no overload for rvalues
```

Which would have been for very little gain. And it's unlikely that the implicitly generated one would ever be for lvalues only. A lot of code (some that even predates C++11) uses assignment on rvalues, without ref-qualifying the operators. So that would break existing code bases.

Comment: Good question is: why is not assignment operator deleted for r-values? I guess it is an overlook in the standard

Comment: "call to an overloaded member function"? What does it mean? Where is it overloaded?

Comment: @bartop - Because assignment to r-values can actually be useful. If you return a proxy object with overloaded assignment, for one example.

Comment: @BartekPL - Classes either define `operator=` or get the compiler generated one.

Comment: @StoryTeller But wait a second. I agree that for some r-values it may make sense. It just disagree it makes sense for `unique_ptr`

Comment: @StoryTeller I know that, but it is weird for me if it is generated for r-values. What is the parameter of that operator?

Comment: @bartop - Code needs to protect users from Murphy, not Machiavelli.

Comment: @StoryTeller I do think disallowing this construction by deleting overload for r-value would make `unique_ptr` usage safer. It would protect from stupid errors

Comment: @bartop - Those don't come up that often in practice. But if you feel this is well worth it, there is always the option of writing a proposal to the C++ standard's committee. It would have to cover more types in the standard library I think, to carry some more weight though.