# What is the logic behind the "lvalueness" and "rvalueness" of a value returned by a function

Tags: c++

In the following code I was expecting the function `Foo f(Foo& x)` to return an rvalue and to my surprise it doesn't. So I started testing some cases to find out the logic behind the "lvalueness" and "rvlaueness" of the returned value. It turns out that returning a named variable of type class is an lvalue. Perhaps I'm missing something

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    int val;
public:
    Foo(int value=10)
    {
        val = value;
    };

    Foo(Foo& other)
    {
        std::cout << "copy ctor used" << std::endl;
        val = other.val;
    };
    Foo(Foo&&)
    {
        std::cout << "move ctor used" << std::endl;
    };
    Foo operator=(Foo& other) 
    {

        std::cout << "copy assign used" << std::endl;
        val = other.val;
        return *this;
    }
    Foo operator=(Foo&& a)
    {
        std::cout << "move assign used" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    void set(int value) { val = value; };
    int get() { return val; };

};


int z = 20;;
int case1()
{
    return z;
};

int case2(int x)
{
    return x;
};

Foo case3(Foo x)
{
    return x;
};

Foo case4(Foo& x)
{
    return x;
};

Foo y;
Foo case5()
{
    return y;
}


Foo& case6(Foo& x)
{
    return x;
};

Foo case7()
{
    Foo x;
    return x;
}



int main()
{
    
    /*case1() = 50;*/ // as expected: not OK the return value is not an lvalue

    int c = 40;
    /*case2(c) = 50; */ // as expected: not OK the return value is not an lvalue
    
    Foo a;
    Foo b = 30;
    case3(a) = b; // OK: not at all expected the return value is an lvalue
                  // I don't see the difference with case 2
                  //copy construction of the argument and return value
                  //copy assigning of b

    case4(a) = b; //OK: behaving exactly like case 3 except for the copy construction
                  // of the argument and the return value
                  // copy assigning taking place as expected

    case5() = b; // same as case 3

    case6(a) = b; //just copy assigning taking place
                  // the same reference to a is returned    

    case7() = b;  // same as before
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong. And your assumption that `=` can only be applied to lvalues in a world where operator overloading is possible is at fault.

Comment: In the case where the function returns `Foo` by value and you assign to it, you are just calling the `operator=` of a temporary object. You could further distinguish those cases by instead providing the different ref-qualifier versions of `operator=`, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/va16J3).

Comment: Another question with a similar topic (though probably not a duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172341/what-is-going-on-here-i-assign-result-to-result-in-c

Comment: Sorry, are you really sure you want to dive into valueness (which is unbelievably complicated with modern C++) at your level of experience?

Comment: @SergeyA we have to deal with such stuff one day or another so sooner is better :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all of your case functions except `case6()` you return by value so you do have an rvalue expression.

The reason `case1()` and and `case2()` don't work but the others do is because the assignment operator for built in types only works on lvalues.  User defined types do not have such a restriction unless you add it yourself by adding a reference qualifier to the assignment operator.

Changing your copy assignment operator to

```
Foo operator=(Foo& other) & //<- notice the & at the end
{
    std::cout << "copy assign used" << std::endl;
    val = other.val;
    return *this;
}
```

will cause all cases except `case6()` to not compile as the trailing `&` says you can only call the copy assignment operator on an lvalue.

Comment: I'm totally convinced with your answer. But, if  I add the declaration  ``Foo c(case4(a))``  expecting the move constructor to be called I get the copy constructor called instead as if the function returned an lvalue!

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar What you are seeing there is copy elision.  In `Foo c(case4(a))` since the function takes by reference it has to make a copy of `a` to populate the return value.  It then elides that copy into the storage that `c` occupies.  Without copy elision you would see a copy and move: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbdee0c96bad1dd8

Answer (score 5):

You can't determine the value category of the return value by checking which constructors get called, because the compiler can in some cases elide copies and moves, eliminate a local variable used to hold a return value (NRVO), and convert copies into moves.

However, the value category rule is simple:

- If the function's declared return type is an lvalue reference, then the return value is an lvalue.
- If the function's declared return type is an rvalue reference, then the return value is an xvalue.
- Otherwise, the return value is a prvalue.

(There is an exception for functions: function values are always lvalues.)

Comment: In all the cases of the example I gave (except for case 6) the return value is neither an lvalue reference nor an rvalue reference so the returned value category is a pvalue! or am I wrong?