# ref-qualifiers for the assignment operator of standard library types

Tags: c++, stl, assignment-operator, std, ref-qualifier

I was wondering, is there a reason the assignment operator of standard types is not lvalue ref-qualified? None of them are.

Because of that, we can write things such as this:

```
std::string{} = "42";
std::string s = "hello " + std::string{"world"} = "oops!";

std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3 };
std::move(v) = { 4,5,6 };
```

If the assignment operator was lvalue ref-qualified all of these examples would not compile.

Is it because there's a lot of things to modify (but then so it was for noexcept) and nobody wrote a proposal for? I don't think people write code like this but shouldn't the library be designed so that it doesn't even allow it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suggestion was [proposed in 2009](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2819.html), and ultimately rejected in Frankfurt that year over ["concerns about backwards compatibility"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2920.html).

It would have been a breaking change, and we don't like those.

The existing prohibition against assigning to rvalues of built-in types is only of limited real value anyway, so the cost of potentially breaking existing code was [almost certainly deemed to be "not worth it"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28598468/560648).

Would the library be designed in this manner if we had a clean slate? Perhaps.

Comment: Bah, just depricate it, wait 6 years, and kill it.  99/100 uses are going to be bugs.

Comment: I see. But what would it break? Anything more than some niche cases?

Comment: @MariusBancila No that's pretty much it, and Adam's right. But still. Seems to me a perfect candidate for a "what were we thinking this was not worth the unexpected catastrophe that has ensued" situation a few years down the line. Don't fix what isn't completely and utterly broken, I guess.